# What are the tests for determining definiteness of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the following criterions but I have few questions:

1)Pivots of a positive definite matrix are positive.What happens if some pivots are zero or negative?If I simply multiply rows with negative pivots with $-1$ then they will be positive, doesn't this violate the test?
2)Sylvester's criterion.It can be used to determine if a matrix is positive or negative definite.What happens if some minor is equal to zero?
3)Test by eigenvalues
4)Test by definition: $x^TAx$

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr  which finds a nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $P^T AP=D$ is diagonal. Then apply Sylvester's Law of Inertia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sylvester criterion notice that you can't say anything in general :

Let $B = (v_{1},v_{2})$ the basis such that $M_{B} (\phi) = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}$

Of course the definiteness of $\phi = (1,1,0)$ which states that $M_{B}(\phi)$ is invertibile because $\phi$ is a nondegenerate form, but for example $M_{B}(\phi_{span(v_{1})}) = 0$

Let $B' = (v_{1}',v_{2}')$ the basis such that $M_{B'} (\phi') = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Now the definiteness is $\phi'=(1,0,1)$ but although $M_{B'}(\phi_{span(v_{2})})$ is completely degenerate $M_{B'}(\phi_{span(v_{1})})$ is not.